# blkparse how to show IO Scheduler message

Tags: blktrace

blktrace version v2.0.0

note: in `blkparse` output, the `m` in the sixth column indicate the line is scheduler information.

1. On Ubuntu 16.04 `ext4` I can see the IO Scheduler message, `blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -i -`

   ```
   8,0    3        1     0.000000000 24714  A  WS 76519424 + 2048 <- (8,1) 76517376
   8,0    3        2     0.000000861 24714  Q  WS 76519424 + 2048 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        3     0.000005084 24714  X  WS 76519424 / 76520768 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        4     0.000008962 24714  G  WS 76519424 + 1344 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        5     0.000009379 24714  P   N [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        6     0.000012021 24714  G  WS 76520768 + 704 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        7     0.000012622 24714  I  WS 76519424 + 1344 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        0     0.000015209     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice insert_request
   8,0    3        0     0.000016074     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice add_to_rr
   8,0    3        0     0.000017548     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice preempt
   8,0    3        0     0.000018184     0  m   N cfq25055SN /user.slice slice expired t=1
   8,0    3        0     0.000018982     0  m   N cfq25055SN /user.slice resid=-2643710186
   8,0    3        0     0.000020125     0  m   N /user.slice served: vt=247310740068 min_vt=247310580285
   8,0    3        0     0.000021297     0  m   N cfq25055SN /user.slice sl_used=33325195 disp=13 charge=13 iops=1 sect=1088
   8,0    3        0     0.000021822     0  m   N cfq25055SN /user.slice del_from_rr
   8,0    3        0     0.000023767     0  m   N cfq workload slice:100000000
   8,0    3        0     0.000024496     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice set_active wl_class:0 wl_type:1
   8,0    3        0     0.000025395     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice dispatch_insert
   8,0    3        0     0.000026232     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice dispatched a request
   8,0    3        0     0.000026818     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice activate rq, drv=1
   8,0    3        8     0.000027030 24714  D  WS 76519424 + 1344 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        9     0.000037848 24714  U   N [TaskSchedulerFo] 1
   8,0    3       10     0.000038118 24714  P   N [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3       11     0.000048153 24714  A  WS 76521472 + 264 <- (8,1) 76519424
   8,0    3       12     0.000048340 24714  Q  WS 76521472 + 264 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3       13     0.000049444 24714  M  WS 76521472 + 264 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3       14     0.000050486 24714  I  WS 76520768 + 968 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    3        0     0.000051332     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice insert_request
   8,0    3       15     0.000051755 24714  U   N [TaskSchedulerFo] 1
   8,0    3        0     0.000052418     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice dispatch_insert
   8,0    3        0     0.000053068     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice dispatched a request
   8,0    3        0     0.000053604     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice activate rq, drv=2
   8,0    3       16     0.000053721 24714  D  WS 76520768 + 968 [TaskSchedulerFo]
   8,0    2        1     0.001844211     0  C  WS 76519424 + 1344 [0]
   8,0    2        0     0.001849143     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice complete rqnoi
   ```
2. on CentOS 7.4 `xfs`,I can not see the IO Scheduler message, `blktrace -d /dev/sdb -o - | blkparse -i -`

   ```
   8,16  25        1     0.000000000 11966  Q   R 73400472 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  25        2     0.000006237 11966  G   R 73400472 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  25        3     0.000007806 11966  P   N [fio]
   8,16  25        4     0.000010836 11966  I   R 73400472 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  25        5     0.000011878 11966  U   N [fio] 1
   8,16  25        6     0.000013900 11966  D   R 73400472 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  10        1     0.008284979     0  C   R 73400472 + 128 [0]
   8,16  10        2     0.008343574 11966  Q   R 73400600 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  10        3     0.008345976 11966  G   R 73400600 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  10        4     0.008346908 11966  P   N [fio]
   8,16  10        5     0.008348926 11966  I   R 73400600 + 128 [fio]
   8,16  10        6     0.008349651 11966  U   N [fio] 1
   8,16  10        7     0.008350694 11966  D   R 73400600 + 128 [fio]
   8,16   8        1     0.008771249     0  C   R 73400600 + 128 [0]
   ```

Comment: @honghe-wu It's not clear what you mean when you say "IO Scheduler message" - which lines in particular? You also forgot to say what sort of disks each of those filesystems were on and what scheduler was in use. It could be that no (or a different) I/O scheduler was being used on each of those systems...

Comment: @Anon in `blkparse` output, the `m` in the sixth column indicate the line is scheduler information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are program version differences between the setups (in [CentOS 7 blktrace is version 1.0.5](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/blktrace-1.0.5-8.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and the kernel is based off 3.10 whereas in Ubuntu 16.04 [blktrace is version 1.1.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/blktrace) and the kernel may be between 4.4 - 4.10) the real point may be down to [what was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975074/blkparse-how-to-show-io-scheduler-message/50850425#comment87231135_49975074) (but unfortunately went unanswered) in one of the comments:

> what [I/O] scheduler was in use

If we look at one of your m lines:

```
8,0    3        0     0.000015209     0  m   N cfq24714SN /user.slice insert_request
```

we can see that it is a [textual message](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git/tree/blkparse_fmt.c?h=blktrace-1.1.0#n412) (hence the m) and that it likely came from the [CFQ I/O scheduler](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/cfq-iosched.txt) (hence the cfq prefix on the message itself). If the I/O scheduler being used for the `/dev/sdb` device on the CentOS 7 setup was not CFQ (e.g. because the [noop I/O scheduler](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/switching-sched.txt) was being used) then we cannot expect similar messages to be present.

So bringing this back to the title of the question:

> blkparse how to show IO Scheduler message

If an I/O scheduler wants to it can send free form `blktrace` text (e.g. see [block/cfq-iosched.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f956d08a56732c61a4d44e8034eeeedfc06fe721/block/cfq-iosched.c#L4129) which has calls to `blk_add_trace_msg()` in it) but not all I/O schedulers do (e.g. see [block/noop-iosched.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f956d08a56732c61a4d44e8034eeeedfc06fe721/block/noop-iosched.c) which doesn't even include the `linux/blktrace_api.h` header). By default [`blkparse` will show all messages present unless you use the `-M` option to suppress them](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git/tree/doc/blkparse.1?h=blktrace-1.1.0#n117).

Comment: Thanks! My CentOS 7.4 uses `noop [deadline] cfq`, instead of Ubuntu 16.04 uses `noop deadline [cfq]`.

Comment: @Honghe.Wu Ah yes, deadline is another I/O scheduler that doesn't output any freeform messages (see  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/block/deadline-iosched.c - no `blktrace_api.h` include and no `blk_add_trace_msg()` calls)

Comment: In fact looking in the 4.10 kernel, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/ident/blk_add_trace_msg shows CFQ is the only I/O scheduler that outputs messages for itself although you may also see them from I/O block throttling, I/O elevator and software RAID systems.